# Sharing visualization with another user via CartoDB?

Tags: carto

Using CartoDB, I would like to share a visualization with multiple users. (The visualization itself, not the resulting map.) I would like for each receiving user to be able to inherit the visualization in their own dashboard.

Sharing the tables loses the link between them and all the custom HTML. Is there a way to share a whole visualization, so that the recipient gets not just KML/GeoJSON, but the tables as a bundle plus the CSS and infowindows?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, sharing a editable visualization is not possible. You can only share them as final maps.

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible with .carto files: https://carto.com/blog/import-export-with-cartodb